# Custom validation of a ModelField in Django

Tags: django

my model looks like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.FloatField(default=0)
    field2 = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

This is how it behaves:

```
>>> m = MyModel()
>>> m.full_clean()

>>> m = MyModel(field1=8.9)
>>> m.full_clean()

>>> m = MyModel(field1='')
>>> m.full_clean()
ValidationError: {'field1': [u'This value must be a float.'], ...
```

I want it to accept blank strings and have it use 0. I also want it to accept values such as "5:56" and have it use "5.93333". (I already have a function that can do this)

Currently I have this working with a custom form field (and it's ugly as sin), but I want to move it all to use model validation. Whats the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `clean_field1` function in your form and verify it in there. Throw a validation error if it's improper, and reformat and return the "proper" value if it is. Example:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Update:

Question clarified: user wants a Model Field that does this.

Override `FloatField` and the `get_prep_value` and `to_python` routines within:

```
class MagicalFloatField(FloatField):
  def to_python( self, value_from_db ):
    ...
    return what_should_go_into_model_field_value
  def get_prep_value( self, value_from_field ):
    ...
    return what_should_go_into_db
```

So you can do the "5:26" <--> "5.26" there. Then use your field in your model:

```
class MagicalModel(Model):
  foo = MagicalFloatField()
```

Reference:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.to_python

Also, for an example of what it expects and how to raise validation errors, look at what you're subclassing -- look up `FloatField` in `site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py`

Comment: I'm not using forms. Also I don't want to have to add a clean_XXX function to every model I am using that field in. I want a custom model field.

Comment: updated, let me know how it works. this should work, but i haven't overridden this particular part of the interface myself before.